# Export Cognos Source Pane

Tags: tree, cognos

Is there a way to export the Tree folders and structure from the Cognos Source Pane (as seen below) ?  I want to be able to view the expanded tree structure in Excel.

Cognos Source Pane

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ynfG.png

Comment: The Cognos Source Pane is not attached to your question.

Comment: What version of Cognos are you using, 11?

Comment: To Jeroen,  the hyperlink in the question is the source pane picture.

Comment: To Damienknight:  10.2.2

Comment: Hi Damienknight.  It is using SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

No, not from the source pane within the Cognos UI.

Comment: If you have an Analytics Administrator license and have access to the model documents and Framework Manager, you may be able to use the Framework Manager SDK to create a C# or Java program to extract that information from the model.